# Publishing an R table in readme.md on Github

Tags: html, r, git, github, html-table

I have created a table in R which I now want to put into the readme.md of my Github repo, but I can't seem to find how. I've tried it using RMarkdown but this didn't work. The table I made is a reactable table, but I wouldn't mind another format, as long as I can display my work on Github.

Comment: Hello there and welcome to StackOverflow, could you post a small example of your table?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mvuorre/exampleRPackage .  It has a `README.Rmd` file which is displayed after conversion to `README.md`.